# Twitter Bootstrap with Visual Force not working(Failed to load Resource)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, salesforce, visualforce

I was trying to integrate `Twitter Bootstrap` with `Visual Force`
Here is my Visual Force code

```
    <apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'css/bootstrap.css')}" />
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'css/bootstrap-responsive.css')}" />
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')}" />

  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'js/bootstrap.js')}"/>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
</head>
  <body>
  <div id="force">

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"> 
      <div class="navbar-inner" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF7F24, #DC143C);"> 
        <div class="container"> 
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </a> 
          <a class="brand" href="#">mypro</a> 
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse"> 
            <ul class="nav"> 
              <li class="active"><a href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html#">Home</a></li> 
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
              <li class="dropdown"> 
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Blogs <b class="caret"></b></a> 
                <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                  <li><a href="#">Thoughts</a></li> 
                  <li class="divider"></li>                  
                  <li><a href="#">Team Blog</a></li> 
                </ul> 
              </li> 
            </ul> 
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right"> 
              <input class="span2" placeholder="Email" type="text" /> 
              <input class="span2" placeholder="Password" type="password" /> 
              <button class="btn" type="submit">Simple form</button> 
            </form> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="container"> 


      <div class="hero-unit"> 
        <h1>Hello, kjhkkhj!</h1> 
        <p>This is a one page demo, showing you how to use Twitter Bootstrap with VF pages, enjoy!</p> 
        For more info on Bootstrap, <a class="btn-custom btn-primary btn-large" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/">Learn more &raquo;</a> 
      </div> 
    </div> 



    <hr /> 

      <footer><label> 
khkjhkhj, 2012</label> 
      </footer> 

  </div>
  </body>
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

But what i get is nothing like `bootstrap`.
when i checked the url in chrome, developer console says `failed to load resource` for all bootstrap files.
Can any one point where i'm going wrong

Comment: I know that is not related with you issue, but try to use a newer jquery lib, 1.8 is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've downloaded the library. Looks like the zip file contains 1 directory called "bootstrap" and only under that one you have "css", "js" etc. That means you'll have to either repack it or reference full relative path (sounds stupid, "full relative", I know). I recommend the latter because it means less work whenever you feel like uploading a new version of the lib. I have same with jQuery mobile.

If prefixing similar to `{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}` won't work - try this:

1. Click "view file" on your static resource (the thing that should prompt you with zip file save window). Copy the path. Will look similar to `https://na5.salesforce.com/resource/1354306153000/jquerymobile`.
2. You can remove the timestamp thing, will still work: `https://na5.salesforce.com/resource/jquerymobile` (I guess they did it to make sure caching gets broken as soon as you upload a fresh resource).
3. Keep adding directory components trying to navigate folder structure until you arrive at something that works. In my case it's `https://na5.salesforce.com/resource/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/images/ajax-loader.gif` and that gives me a pretty good hint what should I put into URLFOR.